# Remove periods at the end of sentences in python

Tags: python, regex, sentence

I have sentences like this - "this is a test. 4.55 and 5,000." 
I want to remove the period at the end of the sentences, but not between numbers. My output has to be - "this is a test 4.55 and 5,000"
I tried the below options, but not getting the required output:

```
wordList = "this is a test. 4.55 and 5,000."
pattern3 = re.compile("[^\w\d]+")
wordList = pattern3.sub(' ',wordList)
```

Also tried the below 2:

```
pattern3 = re.compile("[^\w]|^[0-9]\.[0-9]")
pattern3 = re.compile("[^\w]|^([0-9]/.[0-9]+)")
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. Can someone give me some pointers? I searched the earlier posts and tried them, but they are not working for my situation.

Comment: If you only want to remove the dot at the end of the sentence, why don't you just use `\.$` (with the multiline flag)?

Comment: "I want to remove the period at the end of the sentences, but not between numbers." What should happen to periods that are not at the end of sentence, and also are not between numbers?

Comment: I didn't see any such examples in my sample text. But I believe those should be retained.

Comment: To quote myself: "Purely syntactic approaches using regexps sound problematic... just think of the 5.5 ways that Prof. Smith from the U.S. told us periods can be used."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a negative lookahead:

```
\.(?!\d)
```

What this matches is any period that's not followed by a digit.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I will test it for my entire sample text.

Comment: If you're only dealing with numbers, fine, but periods can show up in the middle of sentences in many more ways: `I've liked Col. Sanders more than Dr. Strangelove since Jan. 29, 1964 ... but I love the U.S. of A. the most.`

Comment: this ought to be the top answer

Answer (score 7):

In regex, the `$` special character ["[matches] the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string"](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

In that case, assuming only one sentence per line, I would suggest the following:

```
\.$
```

This will match only periods that occur at the end of a string (or end of a line for multiline strings). Of course, if you cannot guarantee one sentence per line then they isn't the solution for you.

Comment: Thanks. But, this is not working for all of my text. I have multiple sentences per line.

Comment: @Sarvavyapi Well I'm sorry I couldn't help you. However, I think I will leave my response visible just in case someone in the future finds this question and can use my solution. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: This works fine for the Java code where I need to replace the '.' at the end of the sentence, but not within the sentence, for e.g: This should not replace dots within 'www.abc.com', but will replace the dot from 'End of the sentence.'

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\.(\s)')
wordList = pattern.sub(r'\1', wordList)
```

This replaces a period followed by a space with just the space.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I guess with the large amount of text I have, there will be places where a period may not be followed by a space.

Comment: Hm. So what if you get text like "... more news at 11.6 people were injured in a ..."? Or text like "the method is named foo.bar"?