# How to remove periods from the middle of sentences

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to remove periods from the middle of a string (sentence), leaving the ending period?

The answers that I have seen, basically strip all of the periods.

[Remove periods at the end of sentences in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448401/remove-periods-at-the-end-of-sentences-in-python)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Could you please post your code? A tip: how about removing all periods and adding a period at the end if there was one there in the first place?

Comment: Show us example input and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you want:

```
import re
string = 'You can. use this to .remove .extra dots.'
string = re.sub('\.(?!$)', '', string)
```

It uses regex to replace all dots, except if the dot is at the end of the string. `(?!$)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so the regex looks for any dot not directly followed by $ (end of line).

Comment: This does exactly what I need, thanks a lot Magnus!

Comment: @Carlos No problem :)