# remove periods, not decimal points

Tags: regex

I have a long string variable (many sentences separated by ".") with some important numerical information, generally with a decimal point (e.g., "6.5 lbs").

I would like to regex out the *all* periods when they appear at the end of a sentence, but leave them when they appear between numbers.

FROM:

```
First sentence.  Second sentence contains a number 1.0 and more words.  One more sentence.
```

TO:

```
First sentence  Second sentence contains a number 1.0 and more words  One more sentence
```

I am doing this in Stata, using Unicode regex functions which follow this standard: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

What I *thought* I was doing in the following is: `replace the period w/ a space when the previous character is a lowercase letter'.

```
gen new_variable = ustrregexrf(note_text, "(?<=[a-z])\.", " ")
```

I find that it will remove one period per line, but will not remove all of them.  Maybe what I need to do is tell it: `do this for all the periods you find satisfying the condition`, but since it's not working the way I think it is already maybe I need an explanation of what it actually is doing.

Bonus points if you can tell me how to remove a period when there is a number followed by a space:

`number is 1.0.  Next sentence` -> `number is 1.0 Next sentence`

EDIT: there are occasionally strings like `end sentence.begin next sentence` without spacing so separating on white space won't handle all of my cases.

Comment: Set the `g`lobal flagon your regex. I would also change the regex to "only remove dots that are followed by a space (or at the end)", ie. `\.(?= |$)`

Comment: I should have been more clear in my description: there are mistakes like ```old sentence.new sentence``` where there is no space.    How do I set a global flag?

Comment: Try `\.(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/ptj9SG/1 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448401/remove-periods-at-the-end-of-sentences-in-python

Comment: In the implementation stata is using I guess that's not enough to remove all periods from a long string?  I am not sure how to set a "global flag" as the first comment recommends.

Comment: Not sure, but I was searching a bit on the function `ustrregexrf` and found this page https://www.stata.com/manuals/fnstringfunctions.pdf Perhaps you might use `ustrregexra` to replaces all substrings.

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1

Maybe,

```
\.(?=\s|$)
```

might be OK to look into.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/0AhvMf/1/)

---

### Method 2

```
\d+\.\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/0AhvMf/1/)

is another option to look at, and it would work by installing the `regex` module:

```
$ pip3 install regex
```

#### Test

```
import regex as re

string = '''
First sentence.  Second sentence contains a number 1.0 and more words.  One more sentence.First sentence.  Second sentence contains a number 1.0 and more words.  One more sentence.
'''

expression = r'\d+\.\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.'

print(re.sub(expression, '',  string))
```

#### Output

> First sentence  Second sentence contains a number 1.0 and more words 
>   One more sentenceFirst sentence  Second sentence contains a number 1.0
>   and more words  One more sentence

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I forgot one case (just edited my question): there are occasional ```word.word``` strings -> there is no space between sentences.  I think the first option will miss those?